# Mean distance from center of multivariate Gaussian distribution

Tags: multivariate-normal-distribution, mad

Say I have a multivariate Gaussian distribution and I want to measure the expected vector distance of points from the mean of this distribution.  If I know the covariance matrix of my mvtgaussian, is there some closed form solution for this?

I'm aware there is a [previous questing asking something very similar](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3901975/what-is-the-average-absolute-deviation-of-a-multivariate-normal-distribution), but there were no responses to that one.

Answer (score 2):

If $$X\sim\mathcal N_p(\mu,\Sigma)$$
the expectation $\mathbb E[||X-\mu||^2]$ (assuming the standard Euclidean distance as the chosen distance) is available as
$$\mathbb E[||X-\mu||^2]=
\mathbb E[\text{tr}((X-\mu)(X-\mu)^\top)]
=\text{tr}\{\mathbb E[((X-\mu)(X-\mu)^\top]\}=\text{tr}\{\Sigma\}
$$
The random variable $||X-\mu||$ is distributed as the squared root of a weighted sum of $\chi^2_1$ variates, the weights being the eigenvalues of $\Sigma$.

Comment: This makes sense, and gives me the distribution of $|| X - \mu ||$ as the square root of a mixture of chi squares.  However, how do I then get the expected value of that squared mixed chi squared distribution?  Is there a solution to that?

Comment: Not that I know, otherwise, obviously, I would have given it!